# Android audio switching from headset to speaker on track change. (Unwanted behaviour)

Tags: android

I've got a music player loosely based on the AOSP music player.

A number of Galaxy S3 users of my app have reported that when a song ends and the next one begins, the audio begins to play through the speaker, despite the headset being connected.

I haven't been able to get in touch with these users (feedback is through app reviews), and I don't know how to debug this particular problem, as it's not a 'crash'. Is there anything I can check for, or a way to prevent it from occurring? It does seem to be only on the Galaxy S3.

I don't have any ideas on how to debug this behaviour, but it is costing me!

Comment: go to your local phone store and ask them to help you try to replicate the problem, chances are they will be interested in your work and happy for a distraction. Just make sure you catch them on a quiet day.

Comment: Without having any more info, it sounds like a bug in the audio HAL implementation of that particular Android version that these phones are running (assuming that the headset still appears as connected to the rest of the system). Could be content-dependent.. some platforms have "low power" and/or tunneled playback modes for certain types of content, so switching songs can result in switch in player types in the MM framework as well as a routing switch at the platform level. They might've missed some case, thereby causing the incorrect routing you describe. But more info really is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments/suggestions. I've heard it's happening on stock GS3, which is weird, but yeah it's really difficult without more info. I might have to find some testers and someone to reproduce the issue, then I can narrow it down and even see if it's happening with th e default music player.